# Chef and Knife - Knife hangs on one when booting an instance on ec2 with three knife jobs

Tags: chef-infra

Randomly, knife seems to hang.  I launch three ami's using the below.

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 106 at Thu Apr  5 20:35:00 2012
knife ec2 server create -r "role[redis_server]" -N redis_singapore_development_1_1_1333629300 -E development --region ap-southeast-1 -Z ap-southeast-1a -I ami-c4622596 --flavor t1.micro -G redis -x ubuntu -S sg_development -i /home/ubuntu/.ec2/sg_development.pem > /tmp/redis_singapore_development_1_1_1333629300
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 107 at Thu Apr  5 20:36:00 2012
knife ec2 server create -r "role[redis_server]" -N redis_singapore_development_1_2_1333629300 -E development --region ap-southeast-1 -Z ap-southeast-1a -I ami-c4622596 --flavor t1.micro -G redis -x ubuntu -S sg_development -i /home/ubuntu/.ec2/sg_development.pem > /tmp/redis_singapore_development_1_2_1333629300
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
knife ec2 server create -r "role[nginx_server]" -N bidder_singapore_development_1_1_1333629300 -E development --region ap-southeast-1 -Z ap-southeast-1a -I ami-c4622596 --flavor t1.micro -G nginx -x ubuntu -S sg_development -i /home/ubuntu/.ec2/sg_development.pem > /tmp/bidder_singapore_development_1_1_1333629300job 108 at Thu Apr  5 20:37:00 2012
```

Two will complete and one will get stuck.  Below is the output of the hanged knife job.  All three boots will work about 20% of the time.  Is there a know issue with knife? I even tried to wait 60 seconds between executing command to no avail.

```
Waiting for server............
Public DNS Name: ec2-122-248-207-247.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Public IP Address: 122.248.207.247
Private DNS Name: ip-10-131-22-222.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal
Private IP Address: 10.131.22.222

Waiting for sshd.done
Bootstrapping Chef on ec2-122-248-207-247.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the startup of the ssh demon is not completing or your knife instance is not able to ssh to the box. I have experienced both of these as impacting me. You are going to need to do some work to figure out what is happening here.

The first step is to determine if ssh is up and running on the box. As a first step, I would look at your AWS Console and see what it shows for the instance in question.

I would also increase the level of verbosity from knife. I always hit knife with the '-VV'option to get as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to the ssh port (22) being blocked on my network. Maybe next time check if you are behind a firewall.